# "А после него — Олега". По какой причине ставится тире?

Tags: пунктуация

> Так, профессор Кембриджского университета Кристофер Эндрю, известный историк британской разведки, указывает Пеньковского "самым крупным агентом британской разведки в рядах советских спецслужб", а вторым после него — Олега Гордиевского[1].

Здравствуйте, по какой причине ставится тире перед "Олега Гордиевского"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто. Тире ставится по причине неполного предложения с пропущенным сказуемым "указывает".

Comment: Я бы откорректировал эту фразу: Не "указывает Пеньковского", а "называет Пеньковского", так как слово "указывает" управляет предложной формой (на кого? на Пеньковского)

Comment: К "пропущенному сказуемому" добавлю, что возникает пауза в этом месте и тире её обозначает.

Comment: Не стоит каждую паузу считать за тире. Это неправильно. Иначе можно было бы писать так: "Он - выйди из дома - пошел по улицам - проспектам и аллеям - после чего зашел к Свете - сестре своей". Есть определённые правила пунктуации, которые не всегда связаны с паузами при чтении. например, вводные слова зачастую сливаются со всем остальным предложением, но при этом их надо выделять.